# ending condition for recursive function call

Tags: python, recursion, function-call

I am new to python.

The below recursive code works as expected, so far so good.
What I am wondering about is why after 5 "loops" it stops calling itself recursively.

```
x=0
def factfunc(n):
    global x    
    x+=1
    print("loop #:", x, "-> ",  end="")
    if n < 0:
        print("returning 'None'")
        return None
    if n < 2:
        print("returning '1'")
        return 1
    print ("n=",n)
    return n * factfunc(n - 1)

print ("Finally returned:", factfunc(5))

Output: 

loop #: 1 -> n= 5
loop #: 2 -> n= 4
loop #: 3 -> n= 3
loop #: 4 -> n= 2
loop #: 5 -> returning '1'
Finally returned: 120
```

Hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: At a certain moment `if n < 2:` will be true, and then no more recursive call is made, but a `return` is executed, and so it doesn't continue to the last statement in the function. When debugging don't look at the value for `x`, but the value for `n`.

Comment: thanks, trincot - I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am supposed to answer my own question, doing it anyway:
Thanks to trincot's comment I believe I have understood now, I think this is what happens:

```
return 5 x                  # not returning anything here, instead calling itself again
    (return 4 x             # not returning anything here, instead calling itself again
        (return 3 x         # not returning anything here, instead calling itself again
            (return 2 x     # not returning anything here, instead calling itself again
                (return 1)  # returning 1 (no more recursive action from now on)
            )               # returning 1 x 2 = 2
        )                   # returning 2 x 3 = 6
    )                       # returning 6 x 4 = 24

# 'finally' returning 5 x 24 = 120

=> 120
```

Hope the above is understandable. Thanks again.